# Generating a random string

Tags: c#, .net, string, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to generate a random string in .NET and convert to bytes, and running into a little difficulty. I'd like the full set of possible characters, and my understanding is that a string can contain any character.

My code is currently as follows:

```
var plainText = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < stringLength; ++j)
{
    plainText.Append((char)_random.Next(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue));
}
byte[] x = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText.ToString());
string result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(x);
```

In theory, `plainText` and `result` should be identical. They're mostly the same, but some of the original characters are lost, seems to be characters in the 55000-57000 range - they're replaced with character 65533.

I'm assuming the problem is with my encoding, but I thought Unicode would handle this properly. I've tried UTF8 and UTF32, but those give me the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: strange?! unicode could be, but when you tested it with utf-32?!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I assume you're producing an invalid UTF-16 string with unpaired surrogate characters.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm writing a test on an encryption library by generating a random Unicode string, encrypting it, decrypting it, and ensuring the input and output are identical.

Comment: Encryption libraries usually operate on bytes or byte blocks, so it might be more worthwhile to simply generate random byte arrays.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks - the encryption library does work specifically with byte arrays, but I'm offering an overload to encrypt strings by converting them to byte arrays first, using whatever encoding the user chooses, then encrypting the byte array. This is why I'm testing random Unicode strings, so I can ensure that the overloads work for Unicode strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the characters in the range 0xD800-0xDFFF (55296-57343), called Unicode surrogate characters, are not valid on their own. They must appear as a pair (0xD800-0xDBFF first, 0xDC00-0xDFFF second) in order to be valid (in the UTF-16 encoding scheme). Alone, they will be treated as invalid characters and decoded to 0xFFFD (65533). C# uses UTF-16 to represent its strings, so that's why you are seeing that output.

You can either choose to filter them out (e.g. calling `_random.Next` until you get a non-surrogate character), or generate legal surrogate pairs whenever you generate a surrogate character.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I hadn't dealt with surrogate characters before.

Answer (score 3):

Those are surrogate characters 55296-57343 (0xD800-0xDFFF). You need to pair them up correctly. A pair of surrogate characters in UTF-16 describes a single unicode codepoint.

You seem to operate on the assumption that a char and a code-point are the same thing. That's not true, there are >2^16 code-points.

I recommend reading the [UTF-16 Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).